# React Router display blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When the server starts, the site displays a blank page. I do everything as in the documentation, but the error does not disappear. I tried to remove `<Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact/>` from the code and just leave `<HomeScreen />`, at that moment everything starts to render as it should, but, accordingly, the whole essence of Route does not work. Completely removed and reinstalled modules and packages, but everything still does not work.

**App.js**

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Header from './components/Nheader'
import Footer from './components/Nfooter'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-5'>
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact/>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap'
import products from '../products'
import Product from '../components/Product'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Last Products</h1>
        <Row>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Product product={product} />
                </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: What version of react router are you using? If you don't know look in your package.json file.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: What version of `react-router` is installed? From your project directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back the version(s). Are there any errors in the console? I don't see any overt issues in your code snippet (*if using `react-router-dom@5`*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First problem:**
Two react-router-dom modules were installed (needed to remove one)

**Second problem:**
In the react-router-dom6 version, you need to write this code:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
  </Routes>
```